# Python - How to append double quotes to a string and store as new string?

Tags: python, string, double-quotes

I am using Python 2.6+ and would like to append double quotes to a string and store it as a new string variable. I do not want to print it but use it later in my python script.

For example:

```
a = 'apple'
b = some_function(a) --> b would be equal to '"apple"'
```

How can I do this? All the solutions that I have looked at so far only work when printing the string.

Comment: I don't understand the use case here.

Comment: I'm sure that if you'll try you'll be able to concatenate strings in Python!

Comment: `'"' + a + '"'`

Comment: `a = "apple"` initially and will end up being `a = '"apple"'` unless `apple` is a variable and not a string to begin with

Comment: What do you mean "only work when printing the string?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm guessing he means they do `print ('"' + a + '"')` instead of `b = '"' + a + '"'`.

Answer (score 23):

Beautiful usage in python

```
b = '"{}"'.format(a)
```

in python 3.6 (or above)

```
b = f'"{a}"'
```

work same!

Comment: Fstrings are Python 3.6+ fyi

Comment: It's awesome! : )

Answer (score 6):

```
b = '"' + a + '"'
```

Notice that I am enclosing the double quotes in single quotes - both are valid in Python.

Comment: Or if you happen to somehow need to `print("\"")` --> `"`

Answer (score 3):

```
def add_quote(a):
    return '"{0}"'.format(a)
```

and call it:

```
a = 'apple'
b = add_quote(a) # output => '"apple"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
def some_function(a):
    b = '"' + a + '"'
    return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 'apple'
    b = some_function(a)
    print(b)
```

### Output:

```
"apple"
```