# join string by comma and put quotes around each element

Tags: python

I have a following string:

```
s_tring = 'abcd,efgh,igkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx,yz'
```

I want to create a list and split it by commas and put quotes around each element like this:

```
some_list = '"abcd", "efgh", "igkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx", "yz"'
```

I have tried doing something like this:

```
some_list = '","'.join(s_tring)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: I recommend looking into [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), or alternatively [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: A duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208090/python-how-to-append-double-quotes-to-a-string-and-store-as-new-string/45208151

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like CSV. Python has a standard-library module that implements the format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single line using the `split` and `join` methods with a list comprehension.

```
s = 'abcd,efgh,igkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx,yz'

print(', '.join([f'"{w}"' for w in s.split(',')]))
# '"abcd", "efgh", "igkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx", "yz"'
```

Comment: That's easily solved by swapping the quotes around the format string.

Answer (score 1):

You must first split the original string into a list of strings and then you can put the quotes round them and finally join with a comma:

```py
s_tring = 'abcd,efgh,igkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx,yz'
parts = s_tring.split(',')
parts = [f'"{part}"' for part in parts]
some_list = ', '.join(parts)
```

An alternative is to join the parts with quotes as well and finally add the missing quotes:

```py
s_tring = 'abcd,efgh,igkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx,yz'
parts = s_tring.split(',')
some_list = '"' + '", "'.join(parts) + '"'
print(some_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split & join

```
string = 'abcd,efgh,igkl,mnop,qrst,uvwx,yz'
string = ', '.join([f'"{x}"' for x in string.split(',')])
print(string)
```

output

```
"abcd", "efgh", "igkl", "mnop", "qrst", "uvwx", "yz"
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic: First let's create a new variable which is empty string in which we can add elements until we get a "," using loop. If we get a "," then we'll change it to a space (" ") and add it to variable so that after completion of loop, we can use `split()` function to remove spaces and append it to an empty list. Your code would be:

```
x="abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop,qrst"
v=""
l=[]
c=0
for i in x:
    if i==",":
        v+=" "
    else:
        v+=i

 for b in v.split():
    l.append(b)
        

print(l)
```

Or simply use `split(",")` and add